# Solve ax+by+cz = k using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have scenario where I need to solve following equation and have some data.
We should have only integer value.

ax+by = c
    The value of which we have a,b and c and need to determine x and y.

```
396x+264y = 1980
Ans :The value of x=5 and y=0

396x+264y = 2508
Ans : The vaule of x=5 and y=2

In future, we may add dz.
396+264y+dz = c(some value)
```

I understand, it can contain multiple solution but I would like to how can I determine those solution. In my scenario is I should be get x, and y integer positive value

is it possible to solve this equation using numpy? I thought, it's like gcd
factor.

Comment: no, it's not. not even in maths. you need more constraint to "solve" such an equation

Comment: I assume you want an integer solution. What makes you think `numpy` is the right tool for this if you don't use arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054906/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51595.html) describing the algorithm to solve the equation `ax + by = c` with all `a,b,c,x,y` integers. As I already commented, `numpy` has nothing to do with this as long as none of `a,b,c` is an array.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking such kind of info.

Comment: The reason is, I feel we should have another answer it's not working in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is an underconstrained problem. There are an infiniteset of solutions to your equations